# Не работает вызов функции

Tags: jquery, javascript

Не могу понять, почему не срабатывает функция. Дебагер в неё даже не заходит.
Собственно код:

```
var list = {
               //не работает
                PrintConnect: function(s) {
                    $('#list').html('<div>'+s+'</div>');
                },

               //работает
                Refresh: function(){
                    $.ajax("./list.php",
                    {
                        data:'action=Refresh',
                        success:list.PrintConnect
                    });
                }

            };
```

**UPD 31.10.2012**
Полный скрипт ниже.
Если  я где-то явно ошибся, плиз, намекните.

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="./jquery.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {

                /*
                 * Настройка AJAX
                 */
                $.ajaxSetup({type: 'post', dataType: 'json'});

                /*
                 * События кнопок и поля ввода
                 */
                $('#btnRefresh').click(list.refresh);

                /*
                 * автообновление списка раз в минуту
                 */                
                setInterval(list.refresh, 30000);
            });
    </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            /*
             * Список подключенных
             */
            var list = {

                refresh: function(){
                    $.ajax("./list.php",
                    {
                        data: 'action=Refresh',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success: list.printConnect,
                        complete:list.onComplete
                    });
                },

                printConnect: function(s) {
                    $('#list').html('<div>'+s+'</div>');
                },

                onComplete: function(){
                    return;
                }

            };

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методом научного тыка нашёл решение:

```
var list = {
                Refresh: function(){
                    $.ajax("./list.php",
                    {
                        data: 'action=Refresh',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success: list.PrintConnect,
                        complete:list.onComplete
                    });
            },

            PrintConnect: function(s) {
                $('#list').html('<div>'+s+'</div>');
            },

            onComplete: function(){
                return;
            }

        };
```

Я ещё не понял почему, но без "complete" запрос выполняеться, но не обрабатывается.
Ещё [нарыл](http://xhtml.co.il/ru/jQuery/jQuery.ajax#callback-functions) это:

> complete вызывается когда запрос
> закончен, будь то провал или успех. Он
> передает объект XMLHttpRequest, а
> также строку, содержащую success или
> код ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, надо писать как-то так:

```
 success: function(data){ list.PrintConnect(data) }
```

Comment: @hakimovis, А чего так не уверенно? ))

Comment: @Deonis, давно не писал на JS, как-то не уверен что из головы правильно всплыло

Comment: Вот не поверите, не сам придумал такой синтаксис :) И в таком виде тоже не работает

Comment: @zenith Тогда могу только посоветовать попробовать вынуть эти две функции из объекта, объявляя их более традиционно. Я обычно использовал такую запись:
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax/test.html',
      success: function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
        alert('Load was performed.');
      }
    });

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите [пример тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/UcbTH/1/)

**UPD**

Посмотрите [этот пример](http://user-help.16mb.com/ajax_via_obj.php). Сравните со своим вариантом (смотреть "*Исходный код страницы*"). Потому, что у меня ощущение, что вы или код в DOM-ready не обернули, или библиотеку не подключили так, как надо.

P.S. В исходном коде всё, что каксается JS, в handler.php - только echo '/ *"текст-рыба"* /'

Comment: добавил в закладки.

Comment: @zenith, обновил ответ. Должно прояснить ситуацию

Comment: @Deonis вставил в вопрос весь скрипт как есть.

Answer (score 0):

А теперь внимание правильный ответ: на момент вызова `setInterval` переменная `list` еще не объявлена)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  /*
   * Список подключенных
   */
  var list = {
    refresh: function(){
                $.ajax("./list.php",
                {
                    data: 'action=Refresh',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: list.printConnect,
                    complete:list.onComplete
                });
            },

            printConnect: function(s) {
                $('#list').html('<div>'+s+'</div>');
            },

            onComplete: function(){
                return;
            }

  };
  $(document).ready(function() {

            /*
             * Настройка AJAX
             */
            $.ajaxSetup({type: 'post', dataType: 'json'});

            /*
             * События кнопок и поля ввода
             */
            $('#btnRefresh').click(list.refresh);

            /*
             * автообновление списка раз в минуту
             */                
            setInterval(list.refresh, 30000);
  });
</script>
```

Либо можно куда-то загонять этот list (`window.list` например), тогда и первый код сработает - при условии, что `document.ready` будет после объявления.